# improper integral and dominated convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

Suppose $f:(a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $\lim_{x\to a+} f(x)=+\infty$

Suppose $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b]$, for some $g：[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ satisfying  $\int_a^b g(x)dx<+\infty$

Can we conclude that

$\lim_{t\to a^+}\int_t^b f(x)dx \leq \int_a^b g(x)dx$  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, we can. First, for sufficiently small $h>0$, we have
$$\int_{a+h}^bf(x)\,dx\leq\int_{a+h}^bg(x)\,dx$$
and since the r.h.s tends to a limit as $h\to 0$, we conclude that the l.h.s is
bounded. Moreover, since $f(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a^+$, we can choose $h>0$
so that $f(x)$ is positive in $(a,a+h)$, and in particular, the integral $\int_{a+h}^bf(x)\,dx$ increases as $h$ decreases to zero. Thus, the function
$h\to\int_{a+h}^bf(x)\,dx$ is monotonically increasing and bounded as $h\to 0^{+}$, hence the limit exists, and obviously is not larger than the integral of $g$.

Comment: Actually the function $h\to\int_{a+h}^bf(x)\,dx$ is monotonically decreasing, assuming f positive.

Comment: Yes, but read carefully what I wrote: I'm looking at the integral when $h$ goes backwards towards zero. Do you follow?

Comment: Yes, but what you wrote is wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what I wrote. You are stubbornly sticking to the formalism by which a function is called increasing if it increases as the parameter increases. While this formalism is true, I was careful to emphasise in two places that $h$ is decreasing. Of course I can reformulate it, by means of sequences, so that everyone will be happy, but I wanted to convey what's going on. I am truly sorry it is not to your taste.